# Gender inclusiveness in academic writing: "they are" or "they is"?

Tags: journals, gender, inclusivity

"A person is doing an experiment, and they are having fun."

This expression sounds grammarly incorrect. "A person" and "they" are the same being, how can we use different "is/are" for the same person?

What is the proper expression here.

Comment: I don't think that this question is specific to academic writing, so maybe it belongs on [elu.se] (after checking that there isn't a duplicate already).

Comment: That sentence (with "they are") is fully grammatical and is standard usage. It doesn't sound weird at all to me as a native English speaker.

Comment: He is / she is / they are. Even when "they" is a single person. "They is" is terribly bad English.

Comment: This is no more strange than the French "vous êtes" or the German "Sie sind", where the plural form of the verb 'to be" can also used to refer to a single person. Note that the expression "grammarly incorrect" also apparently sounds correct to you, when in fact it isn't, so I think the best thing to do here is to accept that as a presumably non-native speaker your ability to distinguish grammatical from ungrammatical constructions in English just by how they sound to you is limited.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an English language question.

Comment: Also, the adverb is "grammatically." Grammarly is an app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, "they" isn't necessarily plural. And language isn't like a computer program or a math equation, created from first principles. So, if "they are" is pleasant to the ear of most native English speaking people then it is the "proper" usage.

Usage, of course, changes over time as the current trend in personal pronouns shows.